# Button to open developer Tools in compiled app

Tags: electron

I'm searching a way to open the developer Tools windows (using a `<button>`) once the app is compiled in exe, when I cannot use shortcut as I do in developer mode.

Comment: what do you use in dev mode and why can't you use the same?

Comment: You car register a shortcut or call a method of main with ipcRender

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a button its better you do it via a shortcut key.

use - https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-localshortcut

The library provides apis to register local shortcuts(as opposed to global shortcuts) to your electron app both on mac and windows.

```
const electronLocalshortcut = require('electron-localshortcut');

function registerShortcuts() {
    electronLocalshortcut.register(mainWindow, 'CommandOrControl+B', () => {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    });
}

app.on("ready", () => {
    registerShortcuts();
});
```

Comment: Life saver answer.